# Using Javafx, trying to resize boxes for a calculator

Tags: java, javafx

So i'm trying to learn javafx by building a simple calculator but I can't seem to make the buttons resize or stop them from sticking to the left side of the window.

```
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.application.Application;


public class CalculatorGUI extends Application{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    TextField tf = new TextField();
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    GridPane gp = new GridPane();

    root.setTop(tf);

    ColumnConstraints cc = new ColumnConstraints();
    cc.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
    cc.setFillWidth(true);
    gp.getColumnConstraints().add(cc);


    gp.add(new Button("7"), 0, 0);
    gp.add(new Button("8"), 1, 0);
    gp.add(new Button("9"), 2, 0);
    gp.add(new Button("/"), 3, 0);

    gp.add(new Button("4"), 0, 1);
    gp.add(new Button("5"), 1, 1);
    gp.add(new Button("6"), 2, 1);
    gp.add(new Button("*"), 3, 1);

    gp.add(new Button("1"), 0, 2);
    gp.add(new Button("2"), 1, 2);
    gp.add(new Button("3"), 2, 2);
    gp.add(new Button("-"), 3, 2);

    gp.add(new Button("0"), 0, 3);
    gp.add(new Button("."), 1, 3);
    gp.add(new Button("="), 2, 3);
    gp.add(new Button("+"), 3, 3);



    root.setCenter(gp);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
    primaryStage.show();
}

}
```

which comes out looking like this

[image: Calculator GUI]

Comment: This [example calculator](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/4344564) might be useful to you as a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the dimension of each buttons separately.
I have made this code.
Just check it..

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CalculatorGUI extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TextField tf = new TextField();
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        GridPane gp = new GridPane();
        gp.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        gp.setHgap(10.0);
        gp.setVgap(10.0);
        root.setTop(tf);

        Button button1 = new Button("1");
        Button button2 = new Button("2");
        Button button3 = new Button("3");
        Button button4 = new Button("4");
        Button button5 = new Button("5");
        Button button6 = new Button("6");
        Button button7 = new Button("7");
        Button button8 = new Button("8");
        Button button9 = new Button("9");
        Button button0 = new Button("0");
        Button buttonDOT = new Button(".");
        Button buttonDIV = new Button("/");
        Button buttonMUL = new Button("*");
        Button buttonSUB = new Button("-");
        Button buttonADD = new Button("+");
        Button buttonEQU = new Button("=");
        setButtonSize(button1);
        setButtonSize(button2);
        setButtonSize(button3);
        setButtonSize(button4);
        setButtonSize(button5);
        setButtonSize(button6);
        setButtonSize(button7);
        setButtonSize(button8);
        setButtonSize(button9);
        setButtonSize(button0);
        setButtonSize(buttonDOT);
        setButtonSize(buttonDIV);
        setButtonSize(buttonMUL);
        setButtonSize(buttonSUB);
        setButtonSize(buttonADD);
        setButtonSize(buttonEQU);

        gp.add(button7, 0, 0);
        gp.add(button8, 1, 0);
        gp.add(button9, 2, 0);
        gp.add(buttonDIV, 3, 0);

        gp.add(button4, 0, 1);
        gp.add(button5, 1, 1);
        gp.add(button6, 2, 1);
        gp.add(buttonMUL, 3, 1);

        gp.add(button1, 0, 2);
        gp.add(button2, 1, 2);
        gp.add(button3, 2, 2);
        gp.add(buttonSUB, 3, 2);

        gp.add(button0, 0, 3);
        gp.add(buttonDOT, 1, 3);
        gp.add(buttonEQU, 2, 3);
        gp.add(buttonADD, 3, 3);

        root.setCenter(gp);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void setButtonSize(Button button){
        button.setPrefHeight(35.0);
        button.setPrefWidth(35.0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you should do is to set grid lines visible for `GridPane`:

```
gp.setGridLinesVisible(true);
```

After that you can see what is wrong with your layout.

Coming back to the code, you add single `ColumnConstraint` to `GridPane` but as documentation says about its method `getColumnConstraints`:

> Returns list of column constraints. Column constraints can be added to explicitly control individual column sizing and layout behavior. If not set, column sizing and layout behavior is computed based on content. Index in the ObservableList denotes the column number, so the column constraint for the first column is at the position of 0.

That basically means that the first element in `gp.getColumnConstraints()`  collection relates to first column, second to second and so on. If you simply add:

```
gp.getColumnConstraints().addAll(cc, cc, cc, cc);
```

Everything will work more-less as expected.

**hint** - to make your buttons automatically resize to grid cell, you can use `AnchorPane` :

```
final Button button = new Button();
final AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane(button);
AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(button, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(button, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(button, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(button, 0.0);
gp.add(anchorPane, 0, 0);
```

But there're probably better ways to achieve that - *update* see James_D comment below.

Comment: You can use `cc.setFillWidth(true)` to have the buttons expand to fill the column (without an `AnchorPane`). Alternatively, you can call `GridPane.setFillWidth(button, true);` on each button. In either case, you will also need to call `button.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);` on each button to allow it to grow as needed. Similar method calls exist for the height.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, ended up going with this method

```
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.application.Application;


public class CalculatorGUI extends Application{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    TextField tf = new TextField();
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    GridPane gp = new GridPane();
    Button btn;
    root.setTop(tf);

    RowConstraints rc = new RowConstraints();
    rc.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
    rc.setFillHeight(true);
    gp.getRowConstraints().addAll(rc,rc,rc,rc);
    ColumnConstraints cc = new ColumnConstraints();
    cc.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
    cc.setFillWidth(true);
    gp.getColumnConstraints().addAll(cc,cc,cc,cc);


    gp.add(btn = new Button("7"), 0, 0);
    btn.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    gp.add(btn = new Button("8"), 1, 0);
    btn.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    gp.add(btn = new Button("9"), 2, 0);
    btn.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    gp.add(btn = new Button("/"), 3, 0);
    btn.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);

    gp.add(btn = new Button("4"), 0, 1);
    btn.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    gp.add(btn = new Button("5"), 1, 1);
    btn.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    gp.add(btn = new Button("6"), 2, 1);
    btn.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    gp.add(btn = new Button("*"), 3, 1);
    btn.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);

    gp.add(btn = new Button("1"), 0, 2);
    btn.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    gp.add(btn = new Button("2"), 1, 2);
    btn.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    gp.add(btn = new Button("3"), 2, 2);
    btn.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    gp.add(btn = new Button("-"), 3, 2);
    btn.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);

    gp.add(btn = new Button("0"), 0, 3);
    btn.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    gp.add(btn = new Button("."), 1, 3);
    btn.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    gp.add(btn = new Button("="), 2, 3);
    btn.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    gp.add(btn = new Button("+"), 3, 3);
    btn.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);


    root.setCenter(gp);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  }
```